# Validation loss increase and constant training accuracy 1D cnn

Tags: python, validation, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm implementing a CNN for speech recognition. The input is MEL frequencies with shape (85314, 99, 1) and the labels are one-hot encoded with 35 output classes (shape: (85314, 35)). When I run the model the training accuracy (image 2) starts high and stays the same over the number of epochs, while the loss on validation (image 1) increases. Hence, it is probably overfitting but I cannot find the origin of the issue. I already decreased the learning rate and played with batch sizes but the results stays the same. Also the amount of training data should be sufficient. Is there another issue with my hyper-parameter settings somewhere?

[image]

[image]

My model and hyper-parameters are defined as follows:

```
#hyperparameters
input_dimension = 85314
learning_rate = 0.0000025
momentum = 0.85
hidden_initializer = random_uniform(seed=1)
dropout_rate = 0.2

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=32, filter_length=3, input_shape=(99, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=16, filter_length=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(35, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(frequencies_train, labels_hot, validation_split=0.2, epochs=10, batch_size=50)
```

Comment: Have you checked if your training data and test data are in the same range and format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using "binary_crossentropy" for a problem of multiple classes. Change it to "categorical_crossentrop".

The accuracy computed with Keras using the binary_crossentropy with a model of more than 2 labels is just wrong.

Comment: Caution, "categorical_crossentropy" is to be used when "only one" of the multiple classes is correct. (If that's the case, go for it).

Comment: Pfff what a stupid mistake... Sometimes you focus on it for too long and just don't see those things anymore. Thank you. Now the loss on val is increasing and the accuracy stays 0. Do you maybe have an idea why that is?

No there are 35 output classes that are all positive... which loss function should I use then?

Comment: keras' default losses are here : https://keras.io/losses/ , mean_squared_error should work (probably not the best option, you need to try others to see which one is better.)

Comment: Thanks I figured it out, I used keras validation split but that doesn't use stratified sampling, hence it only had one class in the val set. Now used sklearn train test split and it is working! Thanks guys for your help.